# Does my Full-Text Index already contain a particular value?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL 2008 R2 table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Search_Name](
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](300) NULL),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Search_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))
```

Performance querying the Name field using CONTAINS and FREETEXT works well.

However, I'm trying to keep the values of my Name column unique.  Searching for an existing entry in the Name column is unbelievably slow for a large number of names (usually batches of 1,000), even with an index on the Name field.  Query plans indicate I'm using the index as expected.

To search for an existing value, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, Name from Search_Name where Name = 'My Name Value'
```

I've tried duplicating the Name column to another column and searching on the new column, but the net effect was the same.

At this point, I'm thinking I must be mis-using this feature.

Should I just stop trying to prevent duplication?  I'm using a linking table to join these search name values to the underlying data.  It seems somehow 'dirty' to just store a whole bunch of duplicate values...

...or is there faster way to take a list of 1,000 names and see which ones are already stored in the database?

Comment: Are you checking 1000 names in a set operation, e.g. an INNER JOIN with a table of prospective names, or by making 1000 round trips from an application? Or some other technique? Why are you checking, i.e. to avoid an INSERT that would fail with a unique index? If so, a MERGE with an OUTPUT clause might let you do a batch INSERT with notification of any rejected names.

Comment: @HABO My client app has the values in a List<string>, and is repeating the above select statement for each entry, so I'm using the '1,000 round-trips' method.  One of my potential workarounds was to just attempt to insert them all, but let a unique index fail individual INSERTs.  SqlBulkCopy didn't seem to be an option, since the entire operation will fail on the first failed INSERT.

Comment: The first change to make is to get the entire list to SQL Server at one time. Whether you do an INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT OUTER JOIN to insert only the rows that do not have duplicates or a MERGE to accomplish the same end, doing it as a set operation will make a big difference in performance. Passing the List<string> as a table-valued parameter (TVP) is a clean way to handle it. Have a look [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) for an example. You can still use an OUTPUT clause to track which rows did or didn't make the cut.

Comment: @HABO You are clearly correct regarding performing the action as a set, rather than individually.  My eventual solution involves SqlBulkCopy to insert the data into a temp table, then merging on the server.  It is amazingly fast compared to my previous effort!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Would you like to answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first change to make is to get the entire list to SQL Server at one time. Regardless of how you add the names to the existing table, doing it as a set operation will make a big difference in performance.

Passing the List as a table-valued parameter (TVP) is a clean way to handle it. Have a look [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) for an example. You can still use an OUTPUT clause to track which rows did or didn't make the cut, for example:

```
-- Some sample existing names.
declare @Search_Name as Table ( Id Int Identity, Name VarChar(32) );
insert into @Search_Name ( Name ) values ( 'Bob' ), ( 'Carol' ), ( 'Ted' ), ( 'Alice' );
select * from @Search_Name;

-- Some (prospective) new names.
declare @New_Names as Table ( Name VarChar(32) );
insert into @New_Names ( Name ) values ( 'Ralph' ), ( 'Alice' ), ( 'Ed' ), ( 'Trixie' );
select * from @New_Names;

-- Add the unique new names.
declare @Inserted as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(32) );
insert into @Search_Name
  output inserted.Id, inserted.Name into @Inserted
  select New.Name
    from @New_Names as New left outer join
      @Search_Name as Old on Old.Name = New.Name
    where Old.Id is NULL;

-- Results.
select * from @Search_Name;
-- The names that were added and their id's.
select * from @Inserted;
-- The names that were not added.
select New.Name
  from @New_Names as New left outer join
    @Inserted as I on I.Name = New.Name
  where I.Id is NULL;
```

Alternatively, you could use a MERGE statement and OUTPUT the names that were added, those that weren't, or both.